# Formatting & Indenting many level of HTML tags

Tags: html

I have read some answers and document. They presented about how to formatting & Indenting HTML. But I can't find any answers tell me how to indent many level html tags. I wrote an email template using table layout, it has 5 level of table. So for the last level I have 80 white spaces for indenting. I almost scroll left and right to edit my code. It's so annoying to do so

[image]

Any ideas for better solution please!

Comment: If that's the level of indentation you are using than indentation is not the issue, it's the way you are organizing your HTML. Your HTML shouldn't be nested at that many levels ... whatsoever..

Comment: This email template I have copied from email announcements about Google Analytics.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place for a question like this, since it is clearly opinion-based and has nothing to do with the programming really, just the appearance of your code and so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you copied may have been written automatically. Nobody wrote it so it's not structured to be easy to read.

Sounds like templates within templates. Each template may have been written by a person then the whole lot put together by automation.

Although there are reasons not to nest code that deeply (you just found one!), I wouldn't say it's a bad thing to without stating why.

If you MUST have it all in one file, use your imagination... First thing I thought was:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <table>
                    <tr>

<!-- ======= NEST 1 ======== -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <table>
                    <tr>
```

### Aside from that

- As mentioned, there's probably a setting in your IDE to use 2 spaces
  instead of 4 for indentation, it's pretty common.
- Try to suss out how the templates-within-templates might be
  structured and use php include() to achieve something similar

Comment: The following is wrong:   

"never use a space to indent your code" ... 

My experience is coders prefer not to use TABS for the exact reason stated, different editors handle tabs differently ... 

If you use spaces (two or four is common), you are in control... No editor will interpret a number of spaces as a different number of spaces ... 

@ProDexorite ... 

(When I have enough Rep I'll post this comment under the relevant answer...)

Comment: Yes, it code is auto generated by google... my though. Because I copied from google email.

Comment: I use 2 spaces and it much better, but not 2 white spaces. I just change my eclips setting Dispayed Tab Width from 4 to 2. But my project is in java not php, I don't know how to use include like the ways php does.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer if you like it please? I'm pretty new here, I'd really appreciate the points :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the two spaces indentation instead of tab indentation.

Please refer link: [html indenting standard, tab or two spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430806/html-indenting-standard-tab-or-two-spaces)

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the comments, this question is not a "problem" we in Stack Overflow tend to solve. More of an opinion-based question.

In the form of an answer I would say that you should **never use a space to indent your code**. Each space is being counted as a character and this may cause some problems with indenting if you move from editing software to another.

Different software indent the code differently, and I believe most of those programs have the settings that let you adjust the amount of indent that comes out with a TAB.

For quick, auto-indent of HTML code, you should use **SHIFT + TAB**, which works in most editors. If it doesn't you're off to indenting each line separately.

Comment: By answering, you are contradicting your original statement by sending the message that such a question is in fact acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My answer is clearly opinion-based, and is by all means as off-topic as the question itself. Seemed like a way too heavy comment and kind of answers the off-topic question. Apologies for causing a hassle.

Comment: Thank you, I always use tabs. That's what my problems is.